# How to Scroll Down in the App Inventor Blocks Editor Window?

Tags: android, scroll, app-inventor

How can you scroll down in the Blocks Editor window?

It lets me scroll down a little, but not to the end of my (lengthy) code.

Comment: Tagged as android. (I assume that's the app-inventor you're talking about.)

Answer (score 2):

Use the scroll bar. You can even drag a block at the bottom or right edge to expand the block editor.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of the Blocks Editor has scroll bars and the handy little view in the upper right that lets you set the focus.

(I'm answering App Inventor questions and this may be old info)